# SWFTools Segmentation Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, flash, pdf-conversion, pdf2swf

I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when converting a PDF to SWF using the pdf2swf from swftools. Has anyone come across this or knows what could be wrong.

The notices I get before the error are:

```
NOTICE File contains jpeg pictures
NOTICE file contains soft masks
NOTICE file contains forms
NOTICE file contains transparency groups
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This may be impossible to help me but worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And try running pdf2swf with "-O 1" flag.

Comment: What does this do? It makes my text very blur and looks like a low res jpg instead vector? 

I cannot find this option in the manual :)

Comment: these are optimization flags provided to pdf2swf. -O <LEVEL>, last time I used pdf2swf, there were 2 levels. level one converts all the polygons to bitmap and level 2 converted everything into bitmaps including text. So with 'O -1' your text shouldn't get blurred unless it is some kind of clipart.

Answer (score 1):

use gdb and attach to the core dump and see what happened...

Answer (score 1):

Check dmesg and you will probably see something similar to:

```
pdf2swf[23607]: segfault at 0 ip 00f88400 sp bf8af690 error 4 in libjpeg.so.8.0.0[f7e000+34000]
```

indicating that the segfault is coming from libjpeg. Downgrading to libjpeg7 solved this issue for me (Fedora Core 12).