# PDF to SWF using swftools.org is not functioning properly

Tags: pdf, flash

When i convert a pdf to swf few files are not converting and during conversion server utilization is very hign which results in server getting hanged. Sometimes i run a loop of hundreds of pdf files and if some pdf is not converted to swf due to some issue it stops at that step and remaining all pdf not converted to swf. Please help to get out of this problems.

Answer (score 0):

I utilize swftools to convert pdf files on the fly, so they can be viewed inside an inline (flash) pdf viewer. With certain documents, I experienced errors (swftools 0.9.2.) - concerning the contents of the pdf. I did a google search and from that, appending an option `-s poly2bitmap` helped to solve this issue. Now, since I call swftools from within a Java application, I would listen at std.err and act upon the errors raised here.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965171/swftools-segmentation-fault) might aswell explain your problem.