# SWFTools Segmentation Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, flash, pdf-conversion, pdf2swf

I know that there are similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965171/swftools-segmentation-fault) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055061/swftools-segmentation-fault)) but non of the answers worked for me.

When running `pdf2swf sample.pdf -v -o sample.swf` i get **Segmentation fault**:

```
...
VERBOSE colorMap pixcomps:3 bits:8 mode:2
NOTICE  File contains jpeg pictures
VERBOSE Drawing 1496x1808 transparent jpeg-image (id 151) at size 1496x1808 (548x663), >256 colors
Segmentation fault
```

The "-O 1" flag didn't work, **dmesg** wasn't helpful:

```
pdf2swf[29304]: segfault at 0000000000000000 rip 00002ac82a6c75b0 rsp 00007fff623484b0 error 4
pdf2swf[32714]: segfault at 0000000000000000 rip 00002b7f2e0145b0 rsp 00007fff68ea90c0 error 4
```

I have a similar servers with swftools working fine and processing the same file successfully. I've tried  installing  both version 0.9.1 as i have on my other server as well as installing the newest version available with no help.

I've installed with the following commands:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" ./configure
make
make install
```

Anyone knows what might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had a problem with one of the installation files that caused this problem. I've re-downloaded the next files:

```
jpegsrc.v8d.tar
freetype-2.3.12.tar.gz
swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz
```

and installed them in the following manner:

```
# Install JPEGlib 8d
tar -zvxf jpegsrc.v8d.tar
cd /var/src/conversion/jpeg-8d
./configure
make
make install
ranlib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
ldconfig /usr/local/lib

# install freetype
tar -zvxf freetype-2.3.12.tar.gz
cd /var/src/conversion/freetype-2.3.12
rm -f config.cache
ranlib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
ldconfig /usr/local/lib
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
./configure
make
make install

# Install SWFTOOL
tar -zvxf swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz
cd /var/src/conversion/swftools-0.9.2
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" 
./configure
make
make install
```

Now everything works, hope this will be helpful to others as well